# c++ windows.h memory increse

Tags: c++, windows

hellow for some reson when i move mouse in window made in
windows.h allocated memory increse, pls help,
and also when mouse is moving screen blink
................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <WinUser.h>
void DrawTirangle(HWND hwnd, POINT vertices[], int r, int g, int b) {
    HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
    HPEN hPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 2, RGB(r, g, b));
    HPEN hOldPen = SelectPen(hdc, hPen);

    HBRUSH hBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(r, g, b));
    HBRUSH hOldBrush = SelectBrush(hdc, hBrush);
    POINT verticesx[] = { {vertices[0].x, vertices[0].y}, {vertices[1].x, vertices[1].y}, {vertices[2].x, vertices[2].y} };
    Polygon(hdc, verticesx, sizeof(verticesx) / sizeof(verticesx[0]));

    SelectBrush(hdc, hOldBrush);
    DeleteObject(hBrush);

    SelectPen(hdc, hOldPen);
    DeleteObject(hPen);
}
#include "sys.h"

LRESULT CALLBACK ScreenProc(HWND hWnd,UINT uMsg,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    HDC hDC = GetDC(hWnd);
    RECT rect;

    GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rect);
    PatBlt(hDC, 0, 0, rect.right, rect.bottom, BLACKNESS);
    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hDC);
    renderer(hWnd);
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam); 
}
void ClearBuffer(HWND hwnd, RECT screenDef) {
    HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
    HPEN hPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 2, RGB(0, 0, 0));
    HPEN hOldPen = SelectPen(hdc, hPen);

    HBRUSH hBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 0));
    HBRUSH hOldBrush = SelectBrush(hdc, hBrush);

    POINT vertices1[] = { {0, 0}, {0, screenDef.bottom}, {screenDef.right + 80, screenDef.bottom},{screenDef.right,0} };
    Polygon(hdc, vertices1, sizeof(vertices1) / sizeof(vertices1[0]));

    SelectBrush(hdc, hOldBrush);
    DeleteObject(hBrush);

    SelectPen(hdc, hOldPen);
    DeleteObject(hPen);
}
class SCREEN {
public:
    SCREEN()
        : m_hInstance(GetModuleHandle(nullptr))
    {
        const wchar_t* CLASS_NAME = L"x64 PxOS";
        WNDCLASS wndClass = {};
        wndClass.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;
        wndClass.hInstance = m_hInstance;
        wndClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);
        wndClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL,IDC_ARROW);
        wndClass.lpfnWndProc = ScreenProc;

        RegisterClass(&wndClass);

        DWORD style = WS_CAPTION | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU;
        int w = 640;
        int h = 480;

        RECT rect;
        rect.left = 250;
        rect.top = 250;
        rect.right = rect.left + w;
        rect.bottom = rect.top + h;
        screenDef.left = rect.left;
        screenDef.top = rect.top;
        screenDef.right = rect.right;
        screenDef.bottom = rect.bottom;
        AdjustWindowRect(&rect, style, false);

        mainBuffer = CreateWindowEx(
            0,
            CLASS_NAME,
            L"x64 PxOS",
            style,
            rect.left,
            rect.top,
            rect.right - rect.left,
            rect.bottom - rect.top,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            m_hInstance,
            NULL
        );
        ShowWindow(mainBuffer, SW_SHOW);
        OldBuffer = mainBuffer;
        OldBuffer1 = mainBuffer;
        ClearBufferI = mainBuffer;
        ClearBuffer(ClearBufferI, screenDef);
        screenDefI = screenDef;
    }
    SCREEN(const SCREEN&) = delete;
    SCREEN& operator = (const SCREEN&) = delete;
    ~SCREEN() {
        const wchar_t* CLASS_NAME = L"x64 PxOS";

        UnregisterClass(CLASS_NAME,m_hInstance);
    }

    bool ProcessMessages() {
        MSG msg = {};
        while (PeekMessage(&msg,nullptr,0u,0u,PM_REMOVE))
        {
            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT) {
                return false;
            }

            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        return true;
    }
    HINSTANCE m_hInstance;
    void SwapBuffers() {
        /*if (bs == 1) {
            bs = 2;
            mainBuffer = OldBuffer;
        }
        else if(bs == 2) {
            bs = 1;
            mainBuffer = OldBuffer1;
        }*/
        
        
    }
    HWND mainBuffer;
    HWND OldBuffer;
    HWND OldBuffer1;
    HWND ClearBufferI;
    int bs = 1;
    RECT screenDef;
    RECT screenDefI;
};
```

Comment: Looks like you are getting a private HDC these need to be released https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdc

Comment: You should not be drawing your window every time that you get a message. Only when you get a `WM_PAINT` message.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `ReleaseDC` for every `GetDC`.

You should only paint your window in response to `WM_PAINT` by calling `BeginPaint`/`EndPaint`.

Comment: ty bro, you helped me so mutch,but i want to draw every update,and WM_PAINT is called on start of application

Comment: There is no such thing as every update. Call `InvalidateRect` in response to mouse clicks and/or a timer if you want to update.